# how to dynamically set imageView height based on its width

Tags: android, imageview

Having some imageViews in a list row.

The count of the imageView in the row are different, i.e. could be three or two imageView.

For the width it could be specified using

```
layout_width="0dp"
layout_weight="1dp"
```

for every imageView in the row. But the problem is the height, it should be 90% of the width of the imageView if the row has two imageView, and 80% of the width is the row has three imageView.

Is there way to do that in xml?
If not, where is the best place to do calc and set the height without too much overhead on the drawing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to do in xml. But this works in code, do it in the adapter::getView(), after get the corresponding imagView, change its height layoutParam but keep the width one.

```
Point size = new Point();

((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;

int columnNumber = (isItThree ? 3 : 2);
double ratio = (isItThree ? 0.8 : 0.9)

int desiredImageHeight = screenWidth/colunmNumber * ratio;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams imglayoutParams = imgView.getLayoutParams();
imglayoutParams.height = desiredImageHeight;
imgView.setLayoutParams(imglayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the ratio between height and width the best practice is:
Defining one of its property with a value in dp and another with wrap content.

In your case:

```
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_heignt="wrap_content"
```

By doing this the height should be adjusted according to the ratio of given width.

Comment: not sure how the layout_heignt="wrap_content" will achieve this. In my case the width is dynamic based on the device width (laout:weight=1"dp" for each imageView), and the height will be 90% of the final width.